# Clear PhpExplorer Window

Tags: php, eclipse

The PhpExplorer window on my Eclipse shows each and every project that was ever opened. I am able to do close project but I cannot get that folder away from my eyes. Is there a way that is similar to "cls" on DOS that, it would clear all the projects from this windows and then I can open only the ones I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I found

Step 1: Click on right corner of Project Explorer tab and open context menu. Select Filters option from menu.

Step 2: Check Closed Projects option from Filter and press Ok

From:- http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hide-closed-projects-eclipse-project-explorer-view/